# How to decide whether to use Java's Executor or Kotlin's Coroutine for the following example?

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency

Previously, I have the following concurrency code snippet written in Java.

```
public class Utils {
    private static final ExecutorService executorForRepository = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public String updateIdAndOrderThenInsertAsync(Note note) {
        String uuid = note.getPlainNote().getUuid();

        executorForRepository.execute(() -> {
            updateIdAndOrderThenInsert(note);
        });

        return uuid;
    }
}
```

Right now, I need to convert them to Kotlin. There are 2 ways

### Using Java's Executor

```
object Utils {
    private val executorForRepository: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    fun updateIdAndOrderThenInsertAsync(note: Note): String {
        val uuid = note.plainNote.uuid

        executorForRepository.execute {
            updateIdAndOrderThenInsert(note)
        }

        return uuid
    }

    private fun updateIdAndOrderThenInsert(note: Note) {
        // Implementation of updateIdAndOrderThenInsert method
    }
}
```

### Using Kotlin's Coroutine

```
object Utils {
    private val dispatcherForRepository = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).asCoroutineDispatcher()

    fun updateIdAndOrderThenInsertAsync(note: Note): String {
        val uuid = note.plainNote.uuid

        GlobalScope.launch(dispatcherForRepository) {
            updateIdAndOrderThenInsert(note)
        }

        return uuid
    }

    private fun updateIdAndOrderThenInsert(note: Note) {
        // Implementation of updateIdAndOrderThenInsert method
    }
}
```

They look and work in a very similar way. May I know, how I can decide, which is the solution I should go for?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using Kotlin, use coroutines.

Comment: With no more information, there's not any advantage for one or the other. However, it might be easier to rework the coroutine based one to make it async/cooperative, by just making it suspendable. This way, you'd avoid losing error (as it appears to be in your snippet), and the update function returns value asynchronously once update has succeed.